# Drools rules more than one ruleflow-group

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I have some rules and rule flows. I have scenario that I should assign more than one ruleflow-group to a rule. I m in a situation where I cant assign a common rule flow group name. When I gave two rule flow group name like `ruleflow-group "group1" "group2"` it throws error. Is it possible to have something like this above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ruleflow-group on a single rule is not supported and there is no plan to be supported.